# ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar el botón de mi formulario cuando no han escrito nada en los inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, html

¡Hola!

Me gustaría saber como podría deshabilitar el botón de "enviar formulario" para evitar que envíen el formulario vacío, es decir, que se active solo el botón cuando haya cosas escritas en ambos inputs.
Gracias.

```
  <div class="eight columns omega options">
  <p>
    <label for="card01">
      NIF:
    </label>
    <input name="user" placeholder=" " id="card01" class="form__input txt-overflow_ellipsis ember-text-field ember-view" type="text" maxlength="10" required />
    &nbsp;
    <a href="##" onclick="$(&#39;#capaAyudaNIF&#39;).show()" tabindex="0">No tengo NIF
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="pin_number">
      PIN (contraseña):
    </label>
    <input id="pin_number" name="pass" type="password" value="" size="6" maxlength="6" readonly="" required />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#General/Opciones/ReseteoPIN/WELE200M_ReseteoPin_Ini.aspx">¿Has olvidado o no funciona tu PIN?
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando el evento "keyup" en js

```js
    
    //Recuperas los inputs
    const user = document.getElementById('card01')
    const pin = document.getElementById('pin_number')
    
    //Añades el evento keyup
    user.addEventListener('keyup', verificarInputs)
    pin.addEventListener('keyup', verificarInputs)
    
    //Funcion para verificar el contenido de los inputs
    function verificarInputs() {
      
      //Recuperas el valor de ambos inputs 
      const user_value = document.getElementById('card01').value
      const pin_value = document.getElementById('pin_number').value
      
      //Verificas que los campos no esten vacios
      if(user_value.length > 0 && pin_value.length > 0){
    
       //Remueves el atributo disabled del boton
       document.getElementById('boton').disabled = false
    
      }else{
       //Añade disabled si uno de los campos esta vacio
       document.getElementById('boton').disabled = true
      }
    }
```

```html
<input name="user" placeholder=" " id="card01" class="form__input txt-overflow_ellipsis ember-text-field ember-view" type="text" maxlength="10" required />
    
<input name="user" placeholder=" " id="pin_number" class="form__input txt-overflow_ellipsis ember-text-field ember-view" type="text" maxlength="10" required />
       
       
<input name="boton" id="boton" type="button" disabled value="Enviar"/>
```

Puedes encontrar más acerca de este evento en el siguiente enlace:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event

Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por comentar, lo he intentado pero aún así me sigue redireccionando a la página que hay después de mi login. Lo he hecho de esta manera:
Arriba he puesto  esto:
<script src="validar.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
Y abajo  lo demás

Comment: Ah, no, acabo de revisar mejor el código y ahora sí funciona. Graciaaaaas!!!